# Exporting all fields in pcap files into the csv in python

Tags: python, export-to-csv, wireshark, pcap

I want to convert a pcap file into the csv using the python code; but the problem is I should specify precisely what fields to be exported using the tshark library. I want to export all fields. when I dont specify the fields, blank file is exported. the sample code is presented below:

```
tshark -r /root to the file/test1.pcap -T fields -e ip.src > test1.csv
```

I want to remove the special fields to export ALL fields; then accessing the fields in python (using a library like pandas in dictionary format like df["Source"])

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to remove the special fields to export ALL fields;

This is not possible with the CSV (fields) format

```
$tshark -r trace.pcap -T fields
tshark: "-Tfields" was specified, but no fields were specified with "-e".
```

An alternative solution is to use one of the JSON formats (`-T ek|json|jsonraw`) or the XML format (`-T pdml`).

> then accessing the fields in python (using a library like pandas in dictionary format like df["Source"])

In python you could parse the JSON using `json.lodas()` and get a dictionary. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp